# Redirect www to https in express server

Tags: node.js, express

I have installed express server running with out any problem but if i try to route www.example.com to https would be difficult.

I have created https server which listening on default port 443 and express listening on default port 80.

If i enter example.com redirects to https://example.com but if i enter www.example.com it gives not secure so here i need to redirect to https://examle.com. what i have tried but not work.

```
app.get( '/', function(req, res, next) {
     if((req.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') !== 'https')) {
        res.redirect('https://' + req.get('Host') + req.url);
    } else {
        next();
    }
})
```

Here is simple code i tried

```
var enforce = require('express-sslify');

app.use(express.static('./dist/restraunt'));
app.use(enforce.HTTPS());
app.use(redirectUnmatched);

app.listen(port);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);

function redirectUnmatched(req, res) {
    res.redirect("https://example.com");
}
```

Comment: totally off topic but.. i recommend throwing a nginx in front of your nodejs application to deal with the ssl stack and the forced redirect. in general it's advisable not doing client <=> server encryption from within the application that also runs the business logic. heartbleed was a prime example as to why this is not a good idea. who knows what kind of security vulnerability comes next. you also take the burden of processing ssl away from node and you can run multiple node applications behind a single nginx.

Comment: Initially i have configured nginx but i have some problems with opening ports for public, that's why i switch back to express server with out proxy. so there is no possibility to configure this with out nginx?

Comment: it is possible without it but it's just not good practice. also since i rarely tamper with bad practice i cannot really help you here.

Comment: Then i will try to implement with nginx. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: in nginx just create a listen block for port 80 and throw this in there: `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` you also need to specify `server_name`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect www to https then here is solution

put below code in your app.js

```
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {

      var checkHost = req.get('host').substring(0, 4);
      var condition = req.get('x-forwarded-proto') !== "https" || checkHost !== 'www.' || ( req.get('host').indexOf('www.') < 0);//
      if (condition) {
          res.set('x-forwarded-proto', 'https');

          if (checkHost === 'www.' && ( req.get('host').indexOf('www.') >= 0)) {
              res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);
          }
          else {
              res.redirect('https://www.' + req.get('host') + req.url);
          }
      } else {
          next();
      }
    });
```

Comment: if i use above code i can not enter inside app.get(*). i am using express router If i use router.get(*) i get error i can not access my node rest api's

Comment: you want to use for restapi?

Comment: You can use above code in your route file. just replace 
app.get with router.get()

Comment: I do not want to use with router. I must use this root like www.example.com.

Comment: It means in both case either www or non www you want to redirect to https url ?

Comment: is my code giving any type of error to you? if not then replace  : 

`res.redirect('https://www.' + req.get('host') + req.url);` 

with 

`res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);`